# Can we embedding youtube video in Phaser

Tags: html, phaser-framework

I'm working a project using phaser. They want to play video (youtube, or another source) in the website. Can phaser do that ? I already search but not found anything.

Answer (score 0):

For a Phaser version-agnostic solution, keep in mind that Phaser lives in an HTML page and uses JavaScript.

An easy way to handle working with other HTML in your game is to add a container `div` in the same page that includes the game and then use JavaScript to dynamically populate and/or load/display that container.

Since you didn't provide any code for us to work with, some starter code that you would need to customize and expand upon for your needs is below.

```
<body>
    <!-- Phaser game would need to be loaded passing this div's id -->
    <div id="gameDiv"></div>

    <!-- Video -->
    <div id="videoContainer">/* CSS by default would set visibility to hidden and absolute positioning over the game */
        <!-- depending upon how many videos there are, if it's a static video element it could just be added here, or would be empty and populated via JavaScript -->
    </div>
</body>
```

Then within your game have it toggle the visibility of the video container.

```
function playVideo() {
    var el = document.getElementById("videoContainer");
    el.style.visibility = (el.style.visibility == "visible") ? "hidden" : "visible";
    window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

This function could be expanded upon to clear the contents of the `div#videoContainer` and add another video dynamically, have the video start, toggle the visibility of a different container, etcetera.

Josh Morony's [Creating a Shop with Purchasable Items in a Phaser Game](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-shop-with-purchasable-items-in-a-phaser-game/) has a good overview of how to do this, and is what I borrowed from for pieces of the above.